# -Xms option seems to ignored on gke but -Xmx is working

Tags: java, kubernetes, jvm, heap-memory, ksqldb

I'm running java application(ksqldb 0.15.0) on GKE cluster, and passed the java opts `-Xms3G` and `-Xmx5G`.

`-Xmx` option is working well, but `-Xms` options seems not to be effected.

The running command is as follows;

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/ksqldb-rest-app/*: -Xms3G -Xmx5G -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:NewRatio=1 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dksql.log.dir=/usr/logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/ksqldb/log4j.properties -Dksql.server.install.dir=/usr -Xlog:gc*:file=/usr/logs/ksql-server-gc.log:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=102400 io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain /etc/ksqldb/ksqldb-server.properties
```

To investigate, I issued `jstat` command, and the result was like below;

| NGCMN | NGCMX | NGC | S0C | S1C | EC | OGCMN | OGCMX | OGC | OC | MCMN | MCMX | MC | CCSMN | CCSMX | CCSC | YGC | FGC | CGC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192 | 2621440 | 1572864 | 157248 | 157248 | 1258368 | 64 | 2621440 | 1572864 | 1572864 | 0 | 1163264 | 132268 | 0 | 1048576 | 18828 | 505 | 0 | 4 |

Expected value of the sum of `NGCMN + OGCMN` is 3145728 (=3GB), but the actual value is 256.
However, the sum of `NGCMX + OGCMX` is 5242880(=5GB), so `-Xmx` options is correctly effected.

The Host that the pod is running on has 15GB of physical memories.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you share your pod/rs/deployment yaml?

Comment: Can you add your manifest files ?
As far as I know, you can use the `KSQL_HEAP_OPTS` environment variable to configure KSQL JVM Heap.
Are you sure this is the correct way to get the initial heap size ?
Try `jinfo <PID> | grep "InitialHeapSize\|MaxHeapSize"` command.

Comment: @matt_j I Tried, and got result is `InitialHeapSize=3221225472 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxHeapSize=5368709120`, so I found settings is correctly applied. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Xms` sets the *initial* heap size, not the minimum size.

`NGCMN` and `OGCMN` denote the minimum capacity of the new generation and the old generation respectively. These numbers are useless most of the time. What you probably wanted to look at is `NGC`/`OGC` - the *current* capacity of the new generation and the old generation.

You've set `-Xms3G`, and the current heap size is exactly

```
NGC + OGC = 1572864 + 1572864 KB = 3 GB
```

Comment: Thanks you, I misunderstood the meaning of these numbers.